# SharePoint webpart + visual studio + register as safe

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, web-config

I have created a webpart. However it keeps complain that I have not "registered as safe":

"UnsafeControlException: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported."
"could not be found or it is not registered as safe."

Here is manual fix:

I edit this file:
**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config**

and I add this:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="ExampleWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9d97efbc93164680" Namespace="Example_Web_Parts.VisualWebPart1" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

However, how I can do this through Visual Studio? It stupid always manully add this to web.config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How to: Mark Controls as Safe Controls

Steps:

- Open your SharePoint project inside visual studio.
- Select the web part folder for which you want to change the safe
  control entries in web.config file.
- Press F4 to open properties window
- In properties windows there is last entry of properties displaying as
  `Safe Control Entries`
- Click on the eclipse sign in front of `Safe Control Entries` value.
- Inside “Safe Control Entries” pop up window, check for Namespace
  properties inside SafeControlEntry1 properties panel.
- Change value of namespace property according to your namespace and
  class and click ok.
- Save and build the solution and deploy it again.

Now after successful deployment check web.config of site and voilà you’ll find the correct safe type entries of your web part.

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805045.aspx) article for details